# Texture coordinates for custom geometry in SceneKit ios9

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-es, opengl-es2

I am trying to texture the a custom plane shape I created in scenekit on iOS9. I need the texture to spread out and stretch over the entire surface. I have a vertex and fragment shader on an SCNprogram. But it seems I am doing something wrong and fiddling with this all day, I have come to the conclusion that somehow the Texture coordinates I specify are not correct.

My question is, when creating a geometry, does SceneKit create the texture coordinates automatically so when I specify CGpoint(0,0) for one corner of the texture, it automatically maps it to the bottom left corner of the geometry? Or do I have to manually specify the texture coordinates/uv for the geometry I create?

This problem is a part of a larger question posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104369/custom-shader-scnprogram-ios-9-scenekit/34105050#34105050

Please help, I have spent all day tinkering but no success :(